# rails helper path to accept empty params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to pass empty params to a helper path in rails?

Specifically:

```
get 'movies/director/:director', to: 'movies#search_by_director', as: :search_by_director
```

If the URL accepting the director is left empty (*/movies/director/*), I would like *search_by_director_path(nil)* to still run the *search_by_director* action and I would handle the nil value there

Currently what happens when I try *search_by_director_path(@movie.director)* with a nil director is:

> No route matches {:action=>"search_by_director", :controller=>"movies", :director=>"", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:director]

Comment: Is there any reason to have `director` parameter MUST in the path?

Comment: If I don't, then the movies/:id route takes over and routes to #show (with director as :id)

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do in this action view?

Comment: /movies/:id routes to movie#show and I would like /movies/director/:director to route to a list of movies from that director. If an empty director is given, I want to alert the user

Comment: Then Oleander's answer should be able to make it.

Comment: It doesn't.
When doing this, when I provide an empty director string,  `/movies/director/` is routed into `/movies/:id/` (with :id = 'director'). I could probably change my director route to `/director/(:director)` though

Answer (score 0):

How about `get 'movies/director/(:director)', to: 'movies#search_by_director', as: :search_by_director`?